# TextBox.ContextMenuOpening not firing in Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm writing a universal windows app and am trying to get my own Context Menu for a TextBox. Everything works as expected in the Store App, but on the Phone App the ContextMenuOpening event isn't firing. I've tried with holding and tapping a selected text, but it isn't working, the only thing that is happening, is the little circle for Copy showing up.

Here's where I register the Event Handler: (the method is called at page loading)

```
public void FlipViewLoaded()
{
    TextBox textBox = GetChildControl<TextBox>
                          (_imagesFlipView, "ReadOnlyTextBox");

    textBox.ContextMenuOpening +=
        new ContextMenuOpeningEventHandler(Open);
}
```

And this is the handler:

```
private async void Open(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    TextBox textbox = (TextBox)sender;
    if (textbox.SelectionLength > 0)
    {
        var menu = new PopupMenu();
        menu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Get Word", null, 1));
        menu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Get Text", null, 2));

        var chosenCommand = await menu.ShowAsync(new Point());
        if (chosenCommand != null)
        {
            switch (chosenCommand.Id.ToString())
            {
                 // different commands implementations
            }
         }
         else
         {
            Debug.WriteLine("The chosen command is null !!");
         }
      }
      else
      {
            Debug.WriteLine("The selected _text is null !!");
      }
}
```

As I said, it works perfectly in the Store App (the menu shows up when I hold the selected Text or when I right click on it), but the event doesn't even get fired in Phone App.

**EDIT** Here's the part of the xaml code with the TextBox (the rest is just the standard code that comes with the page + a hub):

```
     <HubSection>
            <DataTemplate>
                <FlipView x:Name="ImagesFlipView" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
                          viewmodel:ImagesPageViewModel.FlipView="{Binding ElementName=ImagesFlipView}">
                    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}" />
                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                    <TextBox x:Name="TranslationTextBox" Visibility="Visible" 
                                             Height="80" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                             BorderThickness="0" Margin="5"
                                             Style="{StaticResource MyTextBoxStyle}"
                                             Background="{StaticResource TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}" 
                                             Foreground="White" FontSize="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                    <TextBox x:Name="ReadOnlyTextBox" FontSize="25" IsReadOnly="True" 
                                             Height="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Translations[english]}" 
                                             BorderThickness="0" Foreground="White" Margin="5" 
                                             Style="{StaticResource MyTextBoxStyle}"
                                             Background="{StaticResource TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                             VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                </FlipView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

Comment: Could you provide some code from the UI side, too?

Comment: Done. The only difference with the Store App is that here I use a Hub and there I don't, but the Hub isn't causing the problem (I tried without it too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple, the TextBox does not have a ContextMenuOpening event in WindowsPhone.

So even if you put that code in an universal apps, it cannot happen.

Universal apps only TRY to match windows 8.1 with windows phone. If an event, or a property is not found, and a correspondance is not found, it is simply ignored.

**EDIT**: To complete the answer, what you have to do, is to think of another behavior when you are in your windows phone app. 
Universal apps projects define pre-processing variables, so you can use code like

```
    #if WINDOWSPHONE
var myWindowsPhoneVar = "windowsPhone";
#else
var myWindowsPhoneVar = "!windowsPhone";
#endif
```

I'm not quite sure the preprocessing variable for windows phone is exactly "WINDOWSPHONE" but you won't have trouble finding it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was starting to think this might be it too, even though it's nowhere in the documentation (it actually says this event exist on both platforms). The two variables are WINDOWS_APP and WINDOWS_PHONE_APP and I've already used them in a couple of places, it's just that I can't think of a better way in this particular case.

Comment: What's your case ? Why do you display in your context menu ?

Comment: I have a picture with two textboxes - one with the original text and one with translation (not visible at the beginning). The idea is, when the user selects a word and holds it, a context menu to show up to give him a choice to translate the word (connects to an online dictionary) or the whole text (makes the other textbox visible). A double tap also allows him to translate the whole text, but not the word itself. I could add a Search button to the AppBar, which directly translates the seelcted word when pressed, but I wanted both versions to have the same UX.

Comment: Ok I see. In any case, users from windows phone, and from windows 8 don't necessarily have the same reflexes. So try to keep a unity, and an identity between the apps, but to make slight adjustments regarding the UI depending on the platform is not a bad thing